# SQL 2008 Datawarehouse Collection Agent Fails with Mirrored Databases on instance

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-mirroring

I have a data collection job that fails when a Database on the instance is in Recovery Mode.  The database in recovery is the MIRROR partner in the database mirror.

The Job that fails is as follows.

```
collection_set_1_noncached_collect_and_upload
```

The job consists of the following steps

1. dcexec -u -s 1 -i "INSTANCE03"
2. EXEC [dbo].[sp syscollector purge collection logs]
3. dcexec -u -s 1 -i "INSTANCE03"

The job fails at Step 1.  I have run the steps manually and they all appear to be ok.

If I change the mirror database to be the principal the job completes successfully.

Comment: Ok Stepping through this issue I have discovered one of the first commands issued is a user on the database.  This fails with the following error.  

Msg 954, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
The database "DatabaseNameDB" cannot be opened. It is acting as a mirror database.

Now I guess I need how to work out how to exclude databases from the collection

Comment: use on the database not user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting in touch with Microsoft Support.  I have now discovered this is fixed in a cumulative update.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971640/

Someone delete the question.